# Django - How do I access request object outside views?

Tags: django, request, view

I have a file named `utilities.py` in the `app` directory, which contains small utility functions specific to my app. I will be calling these function from `views.py`. The problem is some utility function requires access to `request` object.

Is there any way to use `request` object outside the view without passing it as argument to the utility function ?

Comment: Don't think so ...

Comment: Why don't you want to use arguments?

Comment: I want to change some legacy code, And passing request as argument, will require a lot of work ? Is there any other way ?

Comment: Finding and implementing a workaround so you don't have to use arguments will involve a lot of work as well, and ultimately lead to a worse solution.

Answer (score -1):

I've made custom `Context` class which I initialize in Django middleware and put the link to the `request` object.

Two important things about:

1. `Context` class must inherit `threading.local` to prevent request leaks when you run your app within multiple threads.
2. Make `Context` as a singleton. I used Singleton metaclass for this.

So, doing that you can get Django request object simply with this call at any part of code:

```
request = Context().request
```